# Java/Libgdx/Kryonet Networking iusse, sending packets causes Lag [Video attached]

Tags: java, android, networking, libgdx, multiplayer

im currently developing a little duengon crawler. I thought lan multiplayer would be a great idea. So i started to implement that using kryonet ^^. But theres one problem. If my client hosts a server,connects to that and sends movement update packets it lags like hell O.o and i dont know why ... normally all should work fine ... First to show you my problem, heres a video i made :

https://youtu.be/3hgHpImhgT4  (Tell me if you cant view it)

And know heres the iusse part, without it dont lag :

```
public void update(){

    gameScreen.player.update();

    if(gameScreen.player.networkPosition.x != gameScreen.player.position.x){
        //Send the player's X value
        PacketUpdateX packet = new PacketUpdateX();
        packet.x = gameScreen.mySelf.position.x;
        network.client.sendUDP(packet);

        gameScreen.player.networkPosition.x = gameScreen.player.position.x;

    }
    if(gameScreen.player.networkPosition.y != gameScreen.player.position.y){
        //Send the player's Y value

        PacketUpdateY packet = new PacketUpdateY();
        packet.y = gameScreen.player.position.y;
        network.client.sendUDP(packet);

        gameScreen.player.networkPosition.y = gameScreen.player.position.y;

    }
    if(gameScreen.player.netState != gameScreen.player.state){


        PacketUpdateState packet = new PacketUpdateState();
        packet.state = gameScreen.player.state;
        network.client.sendUDP(packet);

        gameScreen.player.netState = gameScreen.player.state;

    }


}
```

This is being called in the render thread, already tried it with a timer ... didnt changed anything :/.

Heres how i move my player :

```
public void update(){


            state = 0;     

           if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.A) && moveDirections[0]){ 
               position.x -= Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() * 200f;       

               state = 1;

           }
           if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.D) && moveDirections[1]){
               position.x += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() * 200f;    


               state = 2;
               //System.out.println(currentState);
           }
           if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.W) && moveDirections[2]){ 
               position.y += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() * 200f;           

               state = 3;
               //System.out.println(currentState);
           }
           if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.S) && moveDirections[3]){ 
               position.y -= Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() * 200f;

               state = 4;

           }              


}
```

This is being called in the public void update where the iusse is. Thats not all, if you want to know how i create my server, here it is :

```
server = new Server(20000,20000);

.
.
.   

//register all the stuff
server.register();

.
.
.

server.bind(20050, 20055);
server.start();
server.addListener(new ServerProgram());
```

And heres my client :

```
client = new Client(20000,20000);

    // register a few classes...
    client.register(); ....

    client.addListener(this);

    // If still connect, close the connection
    client.close();

    new Thread(client).start();

    client.connect(10000, ServerLocalHost.hostAdress, game.connect_tcp_port, game.connect_udp_port);
```

Does anyone why it lags like hell ? I mean i own a 50k internetline :/. So what did i missed ??

Comment: i think you should handle network on a separated thread, it will cause some freezes if you handle it inside your render making the render stop for some time waiting every package get delivered and return, unless you use UDP.. I can't see the video, youtube says it's private.

Comment: Im using UDP ^^ The server isnt on a seperate thread, client isnt too, i could try to put the iusse part into an seperate thread...

Comment: The video should work now :)

Comment: as i see on the video, you can resolve it just by using a camera.position.lerp to the position instead of just setting the camera pos, after that do the same to your player, interpolate the positions instead of just setting the raw position, it will run smooth.

Comment: Are you sure ? But why it only happens, when i call the client.sendUDP(); part ? Already tried to interpolate, didnt worked either

Comment: it's because the time to send to the server, the server process the event and the client get the response will consume some milisseconds, you are using UDP so it would not interfer to your render but the server will process your request and send the absolute real location of the objects, causing the object flickering on the screen, always when using network you don't set the position given by the server, always interpolate it so it will looks smooth on your client. Read about client-side prediction for more info about it. (i don't know if i can explain it right to you)

Comment: And UDP packets could be processed in the wrong order, some packets first and others last, that's a problem too! sometimes it's better to get a separated thread sending tcp's only with user inputs (Like press the button, released the button, not giving posx,posy for instance), process the event on server and then return to the client.

Comment: Wow never thought that it would be so hard to make a little lan multiplayer game O.o So all i need to do is interpolate my player and lerping the camera ? No other thinks todo ? ^^ Ok, the sperate thread part too :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110412/discussion-between-hllink-and-genaray).